# Enterprise Wlan - Ubiquiti UniFi - connection issues

Tags: enterprise, wifi

Our company has several issues with the Ubiquiti UniFi enterprise W-Lan solution.

We´re using these acess points for our whole building(2 floors – 3000 m2).  Every strategically postion is equipped with a UniFi 3.1.4(upgraded from 2.x.x) access point.

We have  up to 40 active users/access point.

For example, if a user who is connected with AP1 walks down the floor and reaches the range of AP1 the notebooks connects with a different AP like it should but it wont choose the „best“ one.

Same issue for workplace employees, you can sit in front of your desk and the client connects to different AP´s without a reason, this results in connection errors and broken voice calls.

Any ideas?

Best Rick

Additional Information:

- We tested several firmware versions without effect
- We set the transmit power of each AP to maximum
- we have unstable pings to each AP
- sometimes there is a connection but no packets were transmitted
- we tested different channels to prevent signal overlaying

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could try.

1. On the controller, when creating the WLAN Group, enable zero-handoff on the frequency you are using.
2. In the WLAN Group settings, there is a load balancing option that will attempt to roam the clients to an AP with fewer clients in order to provide better throughput.  Try turning this off or increasing the max clients/AP.
3. Check for driver updates for your client.  Most drivers allow you to change the roaming aggressiveness.  This setting may need to be tweaked up/down.

40 Clients/AP is a lot.  Which AP model are you using?  The single chain APs are going to struggle with that kind of saturation.  You might be better served by the Unifi Pro or Unifi AC Access Points in your situation.  Alternatively, you could add another AP in high saturation areas and turn the radio power down to attempt to balance clients across more access points.

Good luck.